# Squelching an ls warning/error

Tags: unix, command-line, ls

This is the command Im running

```
ls -l folder/file{[1-9],[1-9][0-9]}.txt
ls: folder/file[1-9][0-9].txt: No such file or directory
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff  558  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff  250  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff   85  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff   18  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file4.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff    0  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file5.txt
```

I want to squelch the error line I get after the command so that it just doesn't show up the command would just look like

```
ls -l folder/file{[1-9],[1-9][0-9]}.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff  558  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file1.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff  250  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file2.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff   85  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file3.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff   18  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file4.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 Craig  staff    0  7 Jul 18:12 folder/file5.txt
```

Comment: If you're using bash, adding `2> /dev/null` will hide all errors, if that's good enough.

Comment: Oh right! I learned that once! Thank-you

Comment: A well formatted Q and Glad you got your answer, but this would have been more appropriate to http://superuser.com or http://unix.stackexchange.com SO can you delete it, it doesn't really add much to the body of knowledge for programming Qs ;-). Right? Thanks and in the future please post to the appropriate S.E. site for your issues.

Comment: I didn't realize that the other stack exchange sites had different criteria like this. On what basis are you suggesting that it's more appropriate to superuser.com or unix.stackexchange.com? Is there any sort of webchange that explains the difference between all of them and what questions are appropriate to which site?

Comment: @C.Monster : see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic for what is on-topic for StackOverFlow. Help about using a command-line tool doesn't qualify as a programming question (imho).  As you're asking about using `ls`, I would expect that unix.stackexchange would be a better place to ask. Superuser.com also answers Qs about using programs, so you should compare counts of Qs on each site about the topic you need help with and then post the the approriate site. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Turning on the `nullglob` shell option will accomplish this:

```
$ ls file{[0-9],[1-9][0-9]}.txt
ls: cannot access file[1-9][0-9].txt: No such file or directory
file0.txt  file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  file4.txt  file5.txt

$ shopt -s nullglob

$ ls file{[0-9],[1-9][0-9]}.txt
file0.txt  file1.txt  file2.txt  file3.txt  file4.txt  file5.txt
```

Add the shopt command to your .bashrc

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Filename-Expansion